# statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint

Tags: c#, sql

BUTTON CLICK CODE

```
bindingSource1.EndEdit();
            try
            {
                // Delete all the Channels for the current Folder.
                int folderID = (int)RemoveFolderBox.SelectedValue;
                deleteChannels(folderID);

                // Delete the folder itself.
                RSSDataSet1.FolderRow folder = rSSDataSet1.Folder.FindByFolderID(folderID);
                folder.Delete();

                int rowsAffected = folderTableAdapter.Update(rSSDataSet1);

                if (rowsAffected > 0)
                {
                    //statusLabel.Text = "Folder successfully deleted.";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Problem when deleting folder:" + ex.Message);
            }
```

deleteChannels-function:

```
private void deleteChannels(int folderID)
{
    try
    {
       RSSDataSet1.ChannelRow[] channels = (RSSDataSet1.ChannelRow[])rSSDataSet1.Channel.Select("FolderID = " + folderID.ToString());

       foreach (RSSDataSet1.ChannelRow channel in channels)
       {
          int channelID = channel.ChannelID;
          channel.Delete();
       }
       int rowsAffected = channelTableAdapter1.Update(rSSDataSet1);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
       throw ex;
     }
}
```

I'm getting

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_Channel_Folder". The conflict occurred in database
>   "C:\USERS\ADMIN\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\PROJECTS\PROJ RSS\PROJ
>   RSS\BIN\DEBUG\RSS.MDF", table "dbo.Channel", column 'FolderID'. The
>   statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 2):

You have a foreign key reference that would be violated if the item you're attempting to remove was deleted. It looks like `Channel` has `Folder` entities that depend on it.

You will need to delete any dependent `Folder` entities before removing the `Channel`, or set up cascading deletes.

Comment: So I have my code backwards then as I'm trying to delete the Channels first before Folders? or I have have my FK wrong? as Channels are childs of Folder

Comment: If you intended to have Channel be a child of Folder it seems you have the keys established in the wrong direction, based on the error you've posted.